# using $.getJSON() with machine on same subdomain?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, same-origin-policy

My webserver's name is `mybox.ourcorp.ourdomain.com`.  From it I'm trying to make a json call to another server in the same subdomain--`http://otherbox.ourcorp.ourdomain.com/feed`

If I open a browser on my webserver and paste that URL in it I get json data back, no problem.  but putting it into `$.getJSON()` I get no value returned:

```
        $.getJSON('http://otherbox.ourcorp.ourdomain.com/feed', function (json) {
               storeDataFeed(json); //<----json is null
        });
```

Is this a same-origin policy problem?  I wouldn't think so, as they're in the same subdomain?

If so, does `otherbox` have to be setup in some way to work with jsonp in order for me to go that route?

Is there a way to find out why that call to `.getJSON` returns null?  There are no messages in the browser console.

Comment: You could investigate what the server returns and what was the response with chrome developer tools in the networks tab. You should see the URL there and can click on it. If this breaks down to origin, then yes, if possible set up jsonp response on otherbox and do it with jsonp

Comment: yes you have a same origin problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, different subdomain would be considered a cross-domain request (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules).

But, you should be able to use $.ajax with dataType:"jsonp":

```
$.ajax({
 dataType: "jsonp",
 url: "http://otherbox.ourcorp.ourdomain.com/feed",
 success:function(json) {
   storeDataFeed(json); //<----json is null
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  Would you know if the server feeding the json needs any extra configuration to provide the data this way?

Comment: you will need a few extra configuration to support jsonp

Comment: No, I don't think so. 'JSONP' will just change the request by making it appear to the server as a request from a script tag.

Comment: I believe lngs is correct unfortunately-- just learned the hard way.  The json needs to be returned with some extra data and not just a raw json feed.  Thanks for the help however.

Comment: You may need the server to wrap the response in a callback (ie: myCallback({json:data})), and then add the name of this function as the 'jsonpCallback' param on the ajax request (ie: jsonpCallback:'myCallback'). More on jsonp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP